# Payments through PayPal and Credit Card with recurring payment

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring-billing

I am developing a website and I need to receive payments from PayPal and Credit Card. Also I need to have recurring payment option for both payment modes (PayPal and Credit Card). I need to know the following

1. Which PayPal product I have to choose? Payflow Pro or Website
   Payment Pro?
2. Where can I get PHP sample codes which has sample implementation of
   these?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, all of this was easy to find using Google.

> Which PayPal product I have to choose? Payflow Pro or Website Payment Pro?

[Website Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/recurring-payments/) with [Recurring Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_CreateRecurringPayments)

> Where can I get PHP sample codes which has sample implementation of these?

[Sample code](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk)

Comment: Updated to Pro / DoDirectPayment and CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile. Payflow Pro with Recurring Billing is an older product and is US-only. Website Payments Pro (with Direct Payment Recurring Payments) is available in the US, UK and Canada. Payflow Pro doesn't offer 'Pay with PayPal account' functionality either, which Website Payments Pro does (via PayPal Express Checkout).

Comment: "This was easy to find on Google" is a bit of a misnomer -- there is literally a FLOOD of information and documentation from Paypal in a Google search. Some of it is outdated, or contains dead links, or is a huge wall of code with no explanation, etc. I am an experienced developer and **I** get confused by the documentation when I'm changing things or adding new functionality.